# PHP session not working on iframe src pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, safari, header

I am working on website which would be open in i frame on various blog and 3rd party site. Everything is working fine except in safari. Our session is not maintain in safari. I have tried following things.

- added header `header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');`
- added in .htaccess `Header set P3P "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"NOI DSP COR NID CUR ADM DEV OUR BUS\""`

Can you please help/suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari disable third party cookies by default. Try to enable them and see if this works. 
This is a security issue; a lot of browsers disable 3rd party cookie by default.

Comment: We can't ask users to do this setting in there browser to browse our site.

Comment: @DevLakshman PHP by default uses a cookie to store the session id.
~RamSharma, If the session cookie is blocked, the only other way you can get the session id is via the query string, which isn't secure, and isn't an option for a 3rd party site.  You can try to hack around safaris security as suggested in this blog i linked below, but past that safari users are just sol unless they disable the strict security setting in their browser. http://measurablewins.gregjxn.com/2014/02/safari-setting-third-party-iframe.html

Comment: That was my point. 
Il you really want to do this that way, you should look for a Single Sign On solution.

Comment: Yup, I was agreeing with your answer.  Was just adding supplemental information